# How to mock based on method parameter

Tags: php, phpunit

One of my stubbed mock objects has a method which will be called twice in a method that I want to test. How can I write the tests so that both branches in my test method will be coveraged? Code sample (The stubbed object is the cache):

```
public function myMethodToTest($param, $default) {
    if ($this->cache->has($param)) {
         return 'A';
    } else if ($this->cache->has($default)) {
         return 'B';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you also provide code for the test (as far as you've gotten)?

Answer (score 0):

Lifted from the [phpunit documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html), we can start with this example:

```
public function testObserversAreUpdated()
{
    // Create a mock for the Observer class,
    // only mock the update() method.
    $observer = $this->getMockBuilder('Observer')
                     ->setMethods(array('update'))
                     ->getMock();

    // Set up the expectation for the update() method
    // to be called only once and with the string 'something'
    // as its parameter.
    $observer->expects($this->once())
             ->method('update')
             ->with($this->equalTo('something'));

    // Create a Subject object and attach the mocked
    // Observer object to it.
    $subject = new Subject('My subject');
    $subject->attach($observer);

    // Call the doSomething() method on the $subject object
    // which we expect to call the mocked Observer object's
    // update() method with the string 'something'.
    $subject->doSomething();
}
```

Pay attention to the `with()` method call. You can use that to specify an expectation that the method will be called with a specific parameter value and dictate what to return when it happens.  In your case, you should be able to do something like this:

```
$cacheStub->method('has')
    ->with($this->equalTo('testParam1Value'))
    ->willReturn(true);
```

Do that in one test, and you'll test one branch of your code.  In a separate test, you can set up the mock differently:

```
$cacheStub->method('has')
    ->with($this->equalTo('testParam2Value'))
    ->willReturn(true);
```

This test will test your other branch.  You can combine them into a single test if you like, you may have to recreate the mock in between assertions.

See also [this short article](http://archive.gregk.me/2011/phpunit-with-method-argument-matchers/) that has some alternative ways of calling `with()` other than `$this->equalTo()`